# Posting data into Google Charts API - geo map

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, google-visualization

I have developed a series of checkboxes and code that counts the number of boxes that have been checked and by using $POST and a separate PHP file (results.php) I can see the count total -  as well as a confirmation, using ECHO, of the values (in this case ‘Countries’) of the selected checkboxes. Here is a sample of the two pieces of code that work okay for me:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post">
<table width="100%">
<tr class=main><td width=190><h2><input type=checkbox name="continents[]" value="EUROPE"> <ins><b><strong>EUROPE (45 COUNTRIES).   </strong></b></ins></h2></td></tr>
<tr class=main><td width=190><input type=checkbox name="selected[]" value="al"> Albania</td><td width=190><input type=checkbox name="selected[]" value="fi"> Finland</td><td width=190><input type=checkbox name="selected[]" value="lu"> Luxembourg</td><td width=190><input type=checkbox name="selected[]" value="ru"> Russia</td></tr></table><br><br>
```

And the code from the ‘results.php’ file:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['continents'])){ $aCont = $_POST['continents']; }
  if(empty($aCont))
 {
   echo("You didn't select any continents -");
 }
 else
 {
   $M = count($aCont);

     echo("You have travelled to $M continents <br><br> ");
   for($i=0; $i < $M; $i++)
   {
 echo($aCont[$i] . "<br> ");
   }
 }
?>
 <br>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['selected'])){ $aPlace = $_POST['selected']; }
 if(empty($aPlace))
  {
   echo("You didn't select any countries.");
 }
 else
 {
   $N = count($aPlace);

   echo("and have visited $N countries <br><br> ");
   for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
   {
echo($aPlace[$i] . ", ");
   }
 }
?>
```

However, my question is how to post this into Google’s Geo chart API so that it generates a map. I have got a test version of the Google Charts world map working on the same ‘results.php’ file. This works with the Country values manually entered. For example, here is the code with Australia and Canada manually coded (using both the full country name or the 2 digit country code) in the “function drawRegionsMap()” part of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 google.charts.load('current', {
   'packages':['geochart'],
   'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
 });
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

 function drawRegionsMap() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country',   'Visited'],
   ['Australia', 1],['CA', 1],
   ]);

   var options = {
   colorAxis: {colors:['green','green']},
   legend: 'none',
   backgroundColor: '#cce5ff',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 };
```

But how do I get the results values that I am generating earlier (from the selected checkboxes using $POST) so that they are read by the Google API code to generate the map based on that data?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to use php for this case. You can capture the user input with javascript and draw the map with selected data. Do you have any reason  for using php?

Comment: No I haven’t been able to try it yet as I am still away on holiday. I am back in 5 days so will check it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, you don't need to use php for this specific case. You can catch the selected countries on the form submit event and generate the map. It would save a request to the server.

I modified your `drawRegionsMap()` function to accept one parameter (the country array) and generate the map based on it. You will have to add an event listener to the form submit event to capture the selected countries, build the array and pass it to `drawRegionsMap()` function.

```
 function drawRegionsMap(countryArray) {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(countryArray);
   var options = {
   colorAxis: {colors:['green','green']},
   legend: 'none',
   backgroundColor: '#cce5ff',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 };

 document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var countryArray = [['Country',   'Visited']];
 var visitedCountries = document.getElementsByName('countries[]');

    for(var i = 0; i < visitedCountries.length; ++i)
  {
      if(visitedCountries[i].checked){
        countryArray.push([visitedCountries[i].value, 1]);
      }
  }

    drawRegionsMap(countryArray);
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/yvdzo0xp/6/)

However, you can do the same if you still want to use PHP and get the data from the server side. Just make an ajax request to the server to get the country array and pass it to the `drawRegionsMap()` function.

============================================================

> EDIT: Added Ajax method as requested in the comments.

As you have requested to show an example of doing the above using an ajax request, here I've added a simple code sample.

All you have to do is replace the body of this event listener:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e){}
```

(that means, when the button is clicked) to include the ajax call instead of looping through the checkboxe values.

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/gh/get/response.html/Nimeshka/jsFiddleAjax/tree/master/',
        complete: function (response) 
        {
            var countryArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            drawRegionsMap(countryArray);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#status').html('Error getting data from the server!');
        },
    });
});
```

So as you can see above: I'm calling my server side page when the user clicks on the button.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nimeshka/jsFiddleAjax/master/demo.response.html

Assume above is my server side page, if you open it, you will see it prints:

```
[["Country","Visited"],["al",1],["fi",1],["ru",1]]
```

which is a json formatted string which can be converted back to a Javascript array. I get that data from the server, then parse it using `JSON.parse()` method and assign to `countryArray` variable, then simply pass it my `drawRegionsMap(countryArray);` function.

You have to create a page on your server to return the array as I have shown above.

Here is a Fiddle where you can see this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/g3h4y19k/

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask if you need to know anything :)

Comment: @Toby you had a small misunderstanding there. Since you submit the form, you can get all the selected countries in the $_POST variable. Also you don't need the click event. see this https://pastebin.com/PXAWkVfr I changed your `results.php` file (just replace your file with this). This should work. Here's what I changed, I only changed the drawRegionsMap() function. https://pastebin.com/E7Ee8qWe